# Explain or demonstrate integration between JointJS and Node.js

Tags: node.js, jointjs

I'm coming back to JointJS after a year away and I see that it now claims some kind of Node.js support or compatibility. I'm using Node.js and am wondering whether I can leverage this feature. Is there a tutorial which walks me through this or can someone please explain what Node.js model integration offers me for JointJS?

http://www.jointjs.com/ claims "NodeJS support".
The [Git commit log](https://github.com/DavidDurman/joint) contains comments like "create tests for NodeJS environment".

Comment: Isn't JointJS tightly related to DOM? There's no DOM on the server side. I don't see how you would use it on the server side.

Comment: @freakish see updated question for some sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, JointJS supports NodeJS environment. Note that only models are supported (element, link, graph). For example, you can build your graph on the server side, then stringify it to JSON, send it to the client and there you can display that graph:

Install jointjs: `npm install jointjs`

Create your graph in NodeJS:

```
var joint = require('jointjs');
var graph = new joint.dia.Graph;

var el1 = new joint.shapes.basic.Rect({ position: { x: 50, y: 50 }, attrs: { text: { fill: 'yellow' } }});
var el2 = new joint.shapes.basic.Rect({ position: { x: 300, y: 200 }, attrs: { text: { fill: 'yellow' } }});
var link = new joint.dia.Link({ source: { id: el1.id }, target: { id: el2.id } });
graph.addCells([el1, el2, link]);
```

Do what you need with the graph:

```
storeToDBOrSendToClient(graph.toJSON())
```

As long as you work with JointJS models, you can take advantage of all the features of JointJS in NodeJS environment.

Comment: Very interesting! I guess the motivation for this feature is so that I can store the JointJS model in my DB and avoid having to translate it to something the frontend can consume? Currently I've got a MongoDB model and I send a derivation of that to the frontend, so this feature could be useful for me.

Comment: That is one motivation indeed. Another one is that you can have a graph on the server and have some sort of synchronisation between client-server. This allows you to do e.g. something like: graph.on('change', storeToDB) in your server app. We use this in combination with our Channel plugin (part of the commercial extension) that does such synchronisation (effectively implementing real-time collaboration).