# how to use jointjs in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jointjs

I am new user of javascript, jointjs and nodejs.
I use webstorm to build a nodejs project, the file structure is as below:

```
/test
 /bin
   www
 /node_modules
 /public
 /routes
   index.js
   users.js
 /views
   error.jade
   index.jade
   layout.jade
 app.js
 pacakge.json
```

I want to use jointjs to plot flowchart in the node.js project, so I change the index.js as below according to the post:
[Explain or demonstrate integration between JointJS and Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20975782/explain-or-demonstrate-integration-between-jointjs-and-node-js)

index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var joint = require('jointjs');
var graph = new joint.dia.Graph;

var el1 = new joint.shapes.basic.Rect({position: {x: 50, y: 50}, attrs: {text: {fill: 'yellow'}}});
var el2 = new joint.shapes.basic.Rect({position: {x: 300, y: 200}, attrs: {text: {fill: 'yellow'}}});
var link = new joint.dia.Link({source: {id: el1.id}, target: {id: el2.id}});
graph.addCells([el1, el2, link]);

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', {title: 'Express'});
});

module.exports = router;
```

Then, I am confused about how to send the graph.toJSON() object to response? How can I render the graph object in the index.jade?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**how to send the graph.toJSON() object to response?**

you can send data to response via render function like below:

```
res.render('index', {title: 'Express', graph: graph.toJSON()});
```

**How can I render the graph object in the index.jadd**

1. You need to be familiar with jade [Jade Lang](http://jade-lang.com/)
2. Then you can follow this tutorial http://www.jointjs.com/tutorial
3. as there is no server side data for joinjs, you can just run the sample code in browser.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am just still confused about how to deal with the graph object in the client. I do need to exchange between server and client. Would you like to give a sample code about how to accept the graph in html of the client? Should I use graph.fromJSON(graphJSON); in script of client html/jade to get the server data?

Comment: Saw your solution, AJAX is the better way.

Answer (score 0):

I kind of solve the problem by using ajax.

On JS in client

```
$('#search').on('keyup', function(e){
        if(e.keyCode === 13) {
            var parameters = { search: $(this).val() };
            $.get( '/searching',parameters, function(data) {
                // $('#results').html(data);
                // var java = JSON.parse(data);

                var graph = new joint.dia.Graph;

                var paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
                    el: $('#container'),
                    width: 800,
                    height: 200,
                    model: graph,
                    gridSize: 1
                });
                var x = JSON.parse(data);
                graph.fromJSON(x);
            });
        };
    });
```

On server side,

```
var joint = require('jointjs');
var graph = new joint.dia.Graph;

var el1 = new joint.shapes.basic.Rect({
    position: {x: 100, y: 30},
    size: {width: 100, height: 30},
    attrs: {rect: {fill: 'blue'},
    text: { text: 'my box', fill: 'white' }}
});
var el2 = el1.clone();
el2.translate(300);
var link = new joint.dia.Link({source: {id: el1.id}, target: {id: el2.id}});
graph.addCells([el1, el2, link]);
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(graph.toJSON());
res.send(jsonString);
```

However, I still don't know how to render jade on server with jointjs object and directly return the rendered html with svg, if I use res.render('index', {title: 'Express', graph: graph.toJSON()});
Can anybody help about that?Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
var strjson = JSON.stringify(graph.toJSON());

var objjson = JSON.parse(strjson);

graph2.fromJSON(objjson);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.